# How to fit models using parallel processing while using all available cores?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib, ray

In an effort to make fitting multiple models more efficient, I have been trying to use all available CPU's and/or parallelize the process. I found out that quite some `sklearn` functions support the `n_jobs` argument which allows for the use of all CPU cores. This is not available for all models and functions, especially when you have created your own. I have also looked into parallel processing since fitting these models are tasks that are done independently, so it makes sense to do this in parallel.

For multiprocessing, I have looked into the `multiprocessing`, `joblib` and `ray` packages. I created a simple script where I fit three classification algorithms, both in parallel using `ray` and sequentially, see:

```
import time
import ray
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100000, n_features=10, n_informative=5, random_state=123)

models_to_try = ['random_forest', 'ada_boost', 'svc']

start_time = time.time()

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def worker(model, X, y):
    if model == 'random_forest':
        return RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X=X, y=y)
    elif model == 'ada_boost':
        return AdaBoostClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
    elif model == 'svc':
        return SVC(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
    
results = ray.get([worker.remote(model, X, y) for model in models_to_try])

ray.shutdown()

end_time = time.time()
print('Runtime parallel {}'.format(end_time - start_time))

def worker_seq(model, X, y):
    if model == 'random_forest':
        return RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X=X, y=y)
    elif model == 'ada_boost':
        return AdaBoostClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
    elif model == 'svc':
        return SVC(random_state=0).fit(X, y)

start_time = time.time()
results_seq = []
for model in models_to_try:
    results_seq.append(worker_seq(model, X, y))
end_time = time.time()
print('Runtime sequential {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

When I run this code, the parallel method is consistently faster, but the difference in runtime is not much (80 versus 65 seconds), which leads me to a couple of questions:

1. Have I implemented parallel processing correctly?
2. I use `ray.init()` without any arguments, which means all CPU cores are available. However, when I look at my CPU usage none of the cores reach 100% usage. When I apply a `sklearn` function with `n_jobs=-1` however, I do see 100% usage. So how exactly are *all* cores being used?
3. Only 3 function calls are made, does this mean that every function gets it's own core? My system has 8 cores so I would expect every function call to get 2 cores at least, so that the full capacity of the system is being used. If this is not the case, would parallel processing only make sense when you're making a call to a function at least *X* times where *X* is the number of cores in your CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Per default, Ray allocates one CPU per remote task. If you want to change this, you can specify e.g. `@ray.remote(num_cpus=2)` to allocate 2 CPUs to each task.

However, this is just from a scheduling perspective. You will still need to tell your sklearn code to use parallel processing or threading, e.g. using `n_jobs=2`.

So in summary, Ray takes care of scheduling and reserving CPU resources, but your code has to make sure it actually utilizes these resources.

For your specific code example, there won't be a huge benefit of using Ray parallel tasks over sklearns multi threading - multi threading is quite efficient, and the time improvements you observe likely come from being able to parallelize parts that don't benefit from multiple threads. Ray's main strength lies in bringing this code to a distributed setting (e.g. a cluster) without any code changes.

Comment: When you say I still need to tell my code to make full use of the available CPUs, it basically means that I am limited to packages that are able to do that? I am thinking of `statsmodels` for example which IIRC does not have a `n_jobs` kind of argument. Also, judging from what you wrote it makes more sense to parallelize code on a level where a lot of independent function calls are made, e.g. when fitting 3 models for 200 customers seperately, it makes more sense to parallelize on a customer-level, right?